# Headphone insertion receiver not receiving broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am attempting to listen for the insertion of headphones using the system service:

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

  private lateinit var headphoneIntentFilter: IntentFilter
  private lateinit var headphoneReceiver:HeadphoneReceiver


    override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    headphoneIntentFilter = IntentFilter(ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)
    headphoneReceiver = HeadphoneReceiver()

    registerReceiver(headphoneReceiver,headphoneIntentFilter)

   }
}
```

The receiver itself:

```
   class HeadphoneReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
   override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    AppLog.i(TAG,"HeadphoneBroadcastReceived")


    if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) {

        when (intent.getIntExtra("state", -1)) {

            0 -> {

                AppLog.d(TAG, "Headset is unplugged")
                TTSUtils.getInstance(context!!).isEnabled = false

            }

            1 -> {

                AppLog.i(TAG, "Headset plugged in")
                TTSUtils.getInstance(context!!).loadService()

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am not receiving the broadcast at all. I am using a custom fork of OSS android on an embedded device, but I'm hoping the problem is with my code.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and suspect that this started when Android O was introduced. In my case, I cannot work around with the AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY flag. I really need to know the headphones state. Would be great if anyone could help...

Answer (score 0):

Try `ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` filter.

```
/**
 * Helper class for listening for when headphones are unplugged.
 */
private class BecomingNoisyReceiver(private val context: Context) : BroadcastReceiver() {

    private val noisyIntentFilter = IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)

    private var registered = false

    fun register() {
        if (!registered) {
            context.registerReceiver(this, noisyIntentFilter)
            registered = true
        }
    }

    fun unregister() {
        if (registered) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this)
            registered = false
        }
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY) {
            //Pause audio
        }
    }
}
```